# Do Go generics support custom structures?

Tags: go, generics

I'd like to use Go generics to take in two different but identical custom-defined structures (`Apple` and `Orange`) into a function `printColor`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Apple struct {
    Color string
}

type Orange struct {
    Color string
}

func printColor[T Orange | Apple](fruit T) {
    fmt.Println(fruit.Color)
}

func main() {
    apple := Apple{Color: "red"}
    orange := Orange{Color: "orange"}

    printColor[Apple](apple)
    printColor[Orange](orange)
}
```

But, the compiler complains that type T doesn't have a `Color` field:

```
./prog.go:16:20: fruit.Color undefined (type T has no field or method Color)
```

Is this not supported? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you can have structs in type constraints, but field access is disabled. looking forward to Go 1.19

Comment: also just FYI, it's not necessary to pass an explicit type param in `printColor[Apple](apple)` and `printColor[Orange](orange)`, the type param can be inferred from the argument. It's perfectly fine to do that, but it can be less verbose. https://go.dev/play/p/jAhLNSuJloa

Comment: use an interface with a `Color` method?